# Highcharts: show just 1 marker from an arearange type of series

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

So the goal here is to hide one of the 2 markers here. if possible, by a series config or by adding a class with `display:none`

[image]

or is that posible though highcharts? Thoughts?

Comment: Why would you like to hide one marker? To have a separate tooltip? I'm afraid it is not possible with `arearange series` type because this is actually one point with two properties low and high (two markers). So tooltip is displayed to one point with two values.

Comment: One workaround is to use a dummy `line` series to generate the marker, and disable markers on the `arearange` series

Answer (score 1):

https://jsfiddle.net/blaird/7j4a2rLo/1/

I turned the bottom marker hidden using the following CSS

```
#container .highcharts-markers.highcharts-tracker.highcharts-series-hover path:nth-child(2) {
  visibility:hidden
}
```

If you want to hide the top marker, use `nth-child(1)`

I did have to turn off the halo effect to make this work, since the halo is done with one path for both markers.  To turn off the halo use:

```
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
          states: {
              hover: {
                  halo: false
              }
          }
        }
    },
```

If you leave the halo on, it will be the first path in the .highcharts-series-hover `<g>`, so you'll have to adjust your `nth-child`.